# Filters per column in a javascript table (Angular) combined results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I have this `ngx-datatable` for Angular that doesn't support filter by column. I would like to add an input filter for every column (some are strings, some are multiple choices etc) and combine them to a single filter so I can use it to get data with `rxJs` from the backend.

What I have for now:

This is the filter component on every column header:

```
<div class="input-group mb">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="search-addon"><em class="icon-magnifier"></em></span>
    </div>
    <input aria-describedby="search-addon" id="order_id" aria-label="Customer" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" type="text" (keyup)='updateFilter($event)'>
</div>
```

The update filter function

```
updateFilter(event) {

  let columnName = event.currentTarget.id;

  const val = event.target.value.toString().toLowerCase();
  const filteredData = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
    return d[columnName].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
  });
  this.rows= filteredData;
  this.table.offset = 0;
}
```

This works for every column. But how can I combine all the filters and start observing the API response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateFilter()` methods needs to values of all filter inputs, not only the one passed in via `$event`.

One way of doing can be to create an object `filters` in your component and two-way bind it's properties to your search inputs in the column headers. Listen to the `ngModelChange` event and trigger the actual filtering.

```
class MyComp {
   // Other stuff
   filters = {};

   filter = () => {
       // Do the filtering, all filters are set in this.filter object
   }
}
```

In your HTML template bind it and listen to the ngModelChange event to trigger the filtering whenever the value changes (better than using `keyUp`, as it also triggers when the content changes without a key being pressed, e.g. copy-pasting via context menu).

```
<input id="order_id" [(ngModel)]="filters.order_id" (ngModelChange)="filter()" ... />
```